# How to Decrypt xml attribute/Element from xml file

Tags: c#, xml

**In registration from i encrypted my password.
Now in Login Form i want to take that encrypted element and want to decrypt for matching.**

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Username = txtUsername.Text;
        string Password = txtPassword.Text;
        string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Logs/Login.xml");
        XDocument Loginxml = new XDocument();
        var LoginCheck = Loginxml.Descendants("userDetails")
            .Any(x => (string)x.Attribute("Username") == Username && EncDec.Decrypt((string)x.Attribute("Password")) == Password );
        if (LoginCheck)
        {
            DisplayMessage.Visible = true;
            DisplayMessage.Text = "Login Successful";
            Response.Redirect("AdminPage.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayMessage.Visible = true;
            DisplayMessage.Text = "Invalid Username/Password";
        }
    }
```

> 

Comment: XML file:-**<userDetails>
  <userDetails Username="TestAdmin" Password="YhY3rY4RCt9XVUiNfaOKmCMP7HADqexWdFHfXc4k3hQ=" />
</userDetails>**

Comment: Note that for matching passwords, one usually uses a hash function.

Comment: above code not work?

Comment: @lllidan can u explain in short?

Comment: @LeiYang no its not wrkng

Comment: Encrypting a password and then using it just to match subsequent input is a bad practice. As the current answer says, it is possible to encrypt the input the same way you encrypt the password and then check the encrypted strings. As you can see, now you even don't need to decrypt anything. At this point, you should realize that encryption is useless in this case and you should try password hashing functions. These functions produce a number from a string, like encryption does, but there is no way in practice to get the original string from the hash. Thus the password is secure in case of hack.

Comment: Of course when you absolutely need to retrieve the password (although you shouldn't), hashes won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned the common thing to do is to just encrypt the user entered password and see if the encryption's match. if you can decrypt it in a reasonable amount of time its not a very good encryption ;)

Comment: string Username = txtUsername.Text;
            string Password = EncDec.Encrypt(txtPassword.Text);
            string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Logs/Login.xml");
            XDocument Loginxml = new XDocument();
            var LoginCheck = Loginxml.Descendants("userDetails")
                .Any(x => (string)x.Attribute("Username") == Username && (string)x.Attribute("Password") == Password );
            if (LoginCheck)
            {
               
            }
        }

Comment: if i add where in any the it gives me error in if Cannot implicitly convert type 'IEnumerable<XElement>' to 'bool'